# C++: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I am implementing a doubly linked list class of sorts which stores 'buckets' (the nodes), which each contain a predefined number of characters. Each bucket stores a pointer to the next and previous bucket, and the list class (BucketString) stores a pointer to the head Bucket. I am compiling using g++ which throws the error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what(): std::bad_alloc
make: *** [run] Aborted (core dumped)
```

whenever I run the code and add a string of characters to the list, using the following add method, which is contained within my bucket class, and is called from the list class's own methods whenever needed.

Code:

```
std::size_t bucketSizeB;
int filled;
char* str;
Bucket* next;
Bucket* prev;

Bucket::Bucket() : bucketSizeB(7), str(new char[7]), next(NULL), prev(NULL), filled(0)
{}

Bucket::Bucket(std::size_t bucketSizeB_) : bucketSizeB(bucketSizeB_), str(new char[bucketSizeB]), next(NULL), prev (NULL), filled(0)
{}

Bucket::Bucket(const Bucket& rhs) : bucketSizeB(rhs.bucketSizeB), next(rhs.next), prev(rhs.prev), filled(rhs.filled)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < (int) bucketSizeB ; i++)
    {
        str[i] = rhs.str[i];
    }
}

void Bucket::add(std::string line)
{

    int diff = bucketSizeB - filled;    //if the bucket is already partially filled


    std::string tmp = line.substr(0, diff);

    for (std::size_t i = 0 ; i < tmp.length() ; i++)
    {

        str[filled] = line[i];
        ++filled;
    }

    if (line.length() > bucketSizeB)
    {

        next = new Bucket(bucketSizeB);

        next->prev = this;
        next->add(line.substr(diff, line.length()-diff));
    }
}
Bucket::~Bucket()
{
    if (prev)
    {
        if (next)
        {
            prev->next = next;
        }
        else
        {
            prev->next = NULL;
        }
    }
    if (next)
    {
        if (prev)
        {
            next->prev = prev;
        }
        else
        {
            next->prev = NULL;
        }
    }
    delete [] Bucket::str;
}
```

When the error is thrown, the add method is being called from the 'list' class member method append, which works as follows:

```
void BucketString::append (std::string& line)
{
    length += line.length();    //Just a way to store the length of the string stored in this BucketString object

    if (!head)   //If the head node pointer is currently null, create a new head pointer
    {

        head = new Bucket(bucketSize);
    }

    Bucket* tmp = head;

    while (tmp->next)   //Finds the tail node
    {
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    tmp->add(line);   //Calls the Bucket add function on the tail node
}
```

The header file for the bucket class is:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#ifndef BUCKET_H_
#define BUCKET_H_

namespace RBNWES001
{
class Bucket
{

    public:
        //Special members and overloaded constructor
        Bucket(void);
        Bucket(std::size_t);
        Bucket(const Bucket&);
        ~Bucket();
        //Copy Assignment not included because it's not needed, I'm the only one who is gonna use this code! :)

        //Add method
        void add(std::string);

        int filled;
        char* str;
        Bucket* next;
        Bucket* prev;
        std::size_t bucketSizeB;
};
}

#endif
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, but let me ask you: What have you tried? Have you added print-statements to see where the error comes from? Have you used a debugger? (And no, the code you showed is not enough)

Comment: I have added said print statements, which is how I know it's being thrown when this method is called. Strange thing is that the method seems to work properly for the first 70 or so characters added, but then the message is thrown. What more would you like? Unfortunately the 'list' class is pretty long, I'll include the method in the 'list' class (called BucketString) that calls this method, if that helps somewhat.

Comment: bad_alloc is thrown by operator new when it's out of memory. Since add uses recursion, perhaps you are recursion-ing yourself out of memory.

Comment: Add a print-statement before `next = new Bucket(bucketSizeB);` and print `bucketSizeB`, see if it becomes too large.

Comment: Sorry, I see the need now to add more code. Certainly not as local-an error as I thought. But it seems like it's just a memory issue, so I'll print out a whole lot of stuff and see if it finds the problem. Thanks!

Comment: If on linux (maybe create a virtual machine, i use VMware) try running it with valgrind. Otherwise try getting visual studio ultimate (or professional). The trial should be good enough. It has good debugging tools. Check the stack and what line it occurs. ]

Comment: One hint: The copy-ctor seems broken, as `str` is not initialized. OTOH, you don't seem to invoke the copy-ctor. Either remove it (and prevent the compiler from auto-generating one) or fix it. To test if it is needed, just declare it, but don't define it.

Comment: For what it's worth, it seems it is breaking at `next = new Bucket(bucketSizeB);` in the add method. Would this imply that there is something wrong with my memory management in that constructor (can't imagine there would be?) or could it just be that the thing is recursing too many times and my computer just has insufficient memory to create a new object on the stack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works: in my `Bucket(std::size_t bucketSizeB)` constructor the initialiser for `str` should change from `str(new char[bucketSizeB]` to `str(new char[bucketSizeB_])` (ie. use the argument passed to the cosntructor instead of using the bucketSizeB variable).

Comment: Because members are initialized in the order they are declared. You should get a warning for this if your compiler settings are high enough.

Comment: @GManNickG, I don't see why you'd get a warning for his specific error. The `bucketSizeB` variable was defined earlier as a global...

Answer (score 5):

1) You can prevent termination with a try/catch block.

2) It sounds like this is occurring when you execute the program.  It also sounds like "make" executes the program automatically.  Correct?

3) If so, you want to look in a debugger and identify the exact line where it's crashing.

4) I suspect if you trace through the code you'll see that one or more of "diff", "bucketSizeB" and/or "filled" become very large (or negative).  Which would be a bug :)  Which you can easily fix - once you find it.

5) Here's are good tutorials on GDB, if that happens to be a convenient debugger for you:

http://dirac.org/linux/gdb/

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/

http://www.cprogramming.com/gdbtutorial.html

Comment: 1) hides the error and makes things worse, it won't solve the problem. 2) is irrelevant. 3) should be (already is) a comment.